# How to manage nested reducers in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, react-state-management

I have two dashboards which contains similar data and properties that I want to implement in redux. See below.

```
Dashboard 1 : {filters, widgets, custom}
Dashboard 2: {filters, widgets, custom}
```

I want to create my redux state like so:

```
{
dashboards: {
    dashboard1:{
        filter:{ // filter related stuff},
        widgets:{ // widget related state},
        custom:{ // custom state}
    },
    dashboard2: {
        filter:{  // filter related state},
        widgets:{  // widget related state},
        custom:{ // custom state}
    }
},
auth: {// auth related stuff},
...// other state keys
```

}

In order to achieve this I am trying to use combine reducers like this for dashboards

```
// xyz.reducer.js

combineReducers({
filters: filterReducers,
widgets: widgetReducers,
custom: CustomReducers
})
```

now I have created a dashboard reducer, which is called every time user navigates to a certain dashboard. I want to assign this state based on dashboardID. something like -

```
const dashboardReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_DASHBOARD: {
      const { payload } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        [payload.dasboardId]: // all the combined reducer state here
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Can someone suggest me how can I achieve this? I am also open for suggestion if someone have a better 
 way of maintaing this kind of state structure.

Comment: If filters and widgets are properties of dashboards then why do they have their own reducers? Also what is `CustomReducers`? And do you need to access both dashboards at the same time? If not you can have one reducer and then pass necessary data to the one reducer based on what dashboard you're supposed to see. Alternatively, you can have one dashboards reducer with a `dashboards` property. This key will point to an array of dashboards and you determine which one to use based on the id.

Comment: your dashboard quantity is dynamic ? Or is it just fixed with 2 dashboards ?

Comment: @DucHong right now It is dynamic based on the User access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do this as long as you have a way to identify all actions that are relevant to the `xyz` reducer and have away to identify the `dashboardId`.

For your example, assuming the nested reducer from `xyz.reducer.js` is called `xyz`:

```
import xyz from './xyz.reducer.js'; // or whatever

const dashboardReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_DASHBOARD: {
      const { payload } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        [payload.dashboardId]: xyz(state[payload.dashboardId], action),
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Let's say you know all of the action types that the dashboard might need to respond to you and they all have `dashboardId` as a key in the payload you can simply pass all of those along.

```
const dashboardReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_DASHBOARD:
    case UPDATE_DASHBOARD_FILTER:
    case ADD_DASHBOARD_WIDGET:
    //... etc
    {
      const { payload } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        [payload.dashboardId]: xyz(state[payload.dashboardId], action),
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is a little brittle so you may want to do something like assume that any payload with a dashboard id should be passed on:

```
const dashboardReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  const {payload = {}} = action;
  if (typeof payload.dashboardId !== 'undefined') {
    return {
      ...state,
      [payload.dashboardId]: xyz(state[payload.dashboardId], action),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Now you don't need to keep up the list of action types, you just need to ensure that all relevant action creators include a `dashboardId` in their payload.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It looks a really good approach. But when I am trying to implement this, I am able to trigger the actions on nested reducer inside dasboards i.e. filters/widget in my case but their corresponding reducer is not being called. But If i try the regular approach my reducers are working fine.
I have tried the exact same approach which you have suggested, is there something I am missing? do you have any working code samples?

Comment: Here's a super quickly hacked together codesandbox that illustrates the concept: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-vl929 in the reducer file you'll see the use of `addReducer` as a sub-reducer that manages a part of the state of the `channelReducer` which dynamically adds new state at keys that come in through the action payloads.